# matching two valuse with regular exp without and condition

Tags: mysql

**Table name: customer_datails**

```
customer_id           customer_name
101                    Hari prasad
102                    Hari
103                    prasad
104                    Vara Prasad
105                     Sri Hari bandaru
106                    Raja Shekhara Prasad
```

i have above table. i want to display CUSTOMER_ID'S WHO ARE HAVING NAME AS 'Hari' and 'prasad' .  but i need it with 'REGEXP' without and condition. i tried below queries those are  working.

Ex 1)

```
select cistomer_id from customer_details where customer_name LIKE 'Raja' 'Prasad';

 o/p: 106
```

Ex 2)

```
select cistomer_id from customer_details where customer_name LIKE 'Raja' AND 
           customer_name LIKE 'Prasad';

    O/P: 106.
```

i need above query with regexp without "and" condition(means i dont want to use customer_name field more than once in where condition like Ex2)

Comment: Your first query won’t even work because the syntax is invalid, and the second one would not return the record with id 106 either because you are using no placeholder in your LIKE comparison, which makes it work the same as a simple `=`. And what you are actually asking, I don’t even understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script: 
select customer_id from customer_details where first_name in ('Raja','Prasad');

Comment: Is there a `first_name` field in the OP's table?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you care about the order, the following query would work:

```
SELECT customer_id
  FROM customer_details
 WHERE customer_name LIKE '%Raja%Prasad%';
```

If you need them in any order, you have to use `RLIKE`:

```
SELECT customer_id
  FROM customer_details
 WHERE customer_name RLIKE 'Raja.*Prasad|Prasad.*Raja';
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
select customer_id from customer_details where customer_name REGEXP '(.*Raja.*)|(.*Prasad.*)';
```

This may help you